# Rails server not serving assets for some pages

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a relatively simple Rails 4 application (running on nitrous.io) that is doing something peculiar. I have a form that is loaded via a GET request, and when the form page is loaded the rails server is rendering only the HTML, and none of the assets.

```
Started GET "/posts/new" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:16 +0000                                                                                                 
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML                                                                                                                               
  Rendered posts/_comments_form.html.erb (4.1ms)                                                                                                                         
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (22.5ms)                                                                                                       
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 36.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The result is that none of my jQuery bindings (actually, no JavaScript at all) get executed. Therefore the page does not work properly.

If I reload the page (by clicking the Refresh button on the browser), then all the assets get served, all the JavaScript executes and everything works fine.

```
Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 60.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)                                                                                                          


Started GET "/posts/new" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:27 +0000                                                                                                 
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML                                                                                                                               
  Rendered posts/_comments_form.html.erb (2.5ms)                                                                                                                         
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (49.5ms)                                                                                                       
Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 60.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000                                                                             
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000                                                                 
Started GET "/assets/wines.css?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000                                                                                   
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000                                                                               
Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000
Started GET "/assets/posts.js?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000                                                                                    
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 198.84.233.70 at 2013-07-19 06:40:29 +0000
```

Comment: what does your browser say on first pageload? do you get 404s or what?

Comment: are you using Turbolinks? if you are, you probably don't have bindings for `page:change`.

Comment: @jvnill is correct. This problem is caused by turbolinks. I did not realize that it is enabled by default in Rails 4. (@jvnill, make it an answer and I'll give you a checkmark)

Comment: much obliged. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*from the comment above*

in Rails 4, Turbolinks is included by default so you may need to include bindings for `page:change`.